# PHP Reference Array element changed without touching

Tags: php, arrays, reference, operators

```
<?php

$arr = array(1);
$a =& $arr[0];
$arr2 = $arr;
$arr2[0]++;

var_dump($arr);
```

This portion of code outputs `2`.
Why?

We only touched first element of `arr2` which isn't assigned by reference to `$arr`. Doesn't alias to the same array, so why is that?

Comment: Because $arr2 is incremented by 1 at the end, and it's assigned what was in $arr.  I suggest print_r($arr) and look into it there. Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish in this though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign one array to the next, a copy is made. But because the element at `$arr[0]` is a reference rather than a value, a copy of the *reference* is made, so that at the end, `$arr[0]` and `$arr2[0]` refer to the same thing.

This is more about references than arrays. Referenced values are not copied. This applies to objects as well. Consider:

```
$ageRef = 7;

$mike = new stdClass();
$mike->age = &$ageRef; // create a reference
$mike->fruit = 'apple';

$john = clone $mike; // clone, so $mike and $john are distinct objects
$john->age = 17; // the reference will survive the cloning! This will change $mike
$john->fruit = 'orange'; // only $john is affected, since it's a distinct object

echo $mike->age . " | " . $mike->fruit; // 17 | apple
```

See the first user note on [this documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) and also [this one](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php).

Comment: This is weird. It doesn't seem like creating a reference to `$arr[0]` should also turn `$arr[0]` into a reference. I'm surprised that I haven't accidentally run across this by now.